# I can't induce a contradiction by assuming negation, what does that imply?

Tags: logic

Suppose I want to prove that $A \Rightarrow B$. So I assume $A$ and $\neg B$ and hope to arrive at a contradiction. But suppose $\neg B$ does not induce any contradiction - I don't mean "suppose I fail to spot any contradictions", I mean let's pretend I have proven that no contradictions arise (if that's even formally possible to do). Does this mean that I have proven $A \not \Rightarrow B$?

I mean, I have shown that $\neg B$ is consistent with $A$, or that $\neg B \not \Rightarrow \neg A$. But I'm no formal logic expert so I'm not convinced that this is equivalent to $A \not \Rightarrow B$. Help?

Comment: Yeah. Exactly. You've proven that $\neg B$ can co-occur with $A$. Then, $A$ does not necessarily imply $B$.

Comment: "So I assume $\neg B$ ..." - I assume you rather assume both $A$ and $\neg B$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes. Good point.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Or rather, what I've done is to prove that $\neg B \not \Rightarrow \neg A$. I would guess that those statements are equivalent, but logic $\Leftrightarrow$ voodoo sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(A \Rightarrow B) \Leftrightarrow (\neg B \Rightarrow  \neg A)$

The right statement is called the contrapositive.
What they are saying is that the satisfaction of $A$ results in a satisfaction of $B$.

If you happen to show that there are cases where $\neg B$ is satisfied but $\neg (\neg A)$ isn't then you have proved that $\neg B \not \Rightarrow \neg A$. At this point, this is telling us that there are cases where $\neg B $ and $A$ are simultaneously verified. What does this mean? it means that we can have $A$ satisfied and not be satisfied by $B$. Thus it does imply $A \not \Rightarrow B$ and your assumption is correct.

Comment: Ok let's clear this up. $\neg B \not \Rightarrow \neg A$ is the same thing as saying "it's not impossible that $\neg B$ and $A$ are both true", right? You're saying this is equivalent to "there are cases where both $\neg B$ and $A$ are true". This is not completely obvious to me - I guess this implicitly hinges on some assumption that "every true statement implies every other true statement" or something?

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist "It's not impossible..." is not  a rigorous accepted reason to make a mathematical statement. All we can take from that kind of phrase is that we cannot declare the statement in question. It doesn't work like law "innocent until proven guilty".  $\neg B \not \Rightarrow \neg A$ isn't saying it's not impossible, it is actually saying there are cases where both $\neg B and A$ are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

On way to prove $A \Rightarrow B$ is to assume $\neg B$ and arrive at (not a contradiction) but $\neg A$.

If you prove that no contradiction follows from $\neg B$, all that shows is that $\neg B$ is internally consistent. But it doesn't follow that it is consistent with $A$.

For example suppose $A = B$. Showing that $\neg B$ (i.e. $\neg A$) entails no contradiction doesn't show that $\neg B$ (i.e. $\neg A$) is consistent with $A$!

Comment: This is not clear to me. $A = B$? What does that mean? Same as $A \Leftrightarrow B$?

Comment: I mean... in your example, you're saying that $\neg B \Rightarrow \neg A$ because $A=B$. But surely that must imply that $A \Rightarrow B$!?